# django filter by size of many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a PhotoSet class with a many-to-many relationship to a Tag class.

I'd like to select all PhotoSets that have fewer than 5 tags.

There are of course many workaround to do this, but I'd like to know if there is a "Django way" of doing it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, it is achievable using annotations. Since I am not aware of your models, it would look something like this:

```
PhotoSet.objects.values("id").annotate(Count("tags"))
```

[Refer this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations)